# PHP/MySQL: Different versions of Backup and Upgrade version

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, hosting, shared-hosting

I'm working on a shared hosting, and i need to upgrade PHP and MySql version (PHP: 5.2.17 // MySql 5.1.73-community) to install Wordpress without security issues. If i backup, and upgrade versions, this backup will work fine?

What if i only can upgrade PHP version?

Comment: Test the backup on a development machine.  Yes, it should be fine.

Comment: Thx ! i'll test it